# Linking two tables with two (composite) foreign key relation

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

- Version: 3.2.1

**Relations**

Two columns from table B are associated with two columns from table A.

- Table A -> hasMany -> table B
- Table B -> belongsTo -> table A
- B.a_id = A.a_id
- B.a_name = A.a_name

**Cookbook**

No example found in the cookbook. 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

How can I specify these relations? Already tried this:

```
$this->hasMany('B', [
        'conditions' => ['A.a_id' => 'B.a_id', 'A.a_name' => 'B.a_name']
    ]);
```

And this:

```
$this->hasMany('B1', [
        'foreignKey' => 'a_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
        'className' => 'B'
    ]);

$this->hasMany('B2', [
        'foreignKey' => 'a_name',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
        'className' => 'B'
    ]);
```

Comment: So what you have there is a composite foreign key?

Comment: Yes, this is a composite foreign key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composite keys can be specified using arrays, this is supported for foreign keys as well as primary keys nearly everywhere.

```
$this->hasMany('B', [
    'foreignKey' => [
        'a_id',
        'a_name'
    ],
    'bindingKey' => [
        'a_id',
        'a_name'
    ]
]);
```

An example in the docs wouldn't hurt, you may want to open a ticket [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues).

ps. `hasMany` associations do not support a `joinType` option.

Comment: Thanks again for the great answer. This solved the first problem and this is also the solution for the other way arround (belongsTo('A')...). I opened a ticket on GitHub with a link to this stackoverflow post.